# WinRM client sent a request to an HTTP server, while opening Runspace in WinRM

Tags: c#, powershell, winrm

I am trying to access the Remote system service details using powershell `System.Management.Automation` dll.

When i am executing the below code to connect to the remote system I am facing the error:

Code snippet:

```
string shellUri = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.PowerShell";
PSCredential remoteCredential = new PSCredential("uname", this.convertToSecureString("password"));
WSManConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(new Uri("http://machinename/powershell"), shellUri, remoteCredential);
connectionInfo.AuthenticationMechanism = AuthenticationMechanism.Kerberos;
Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectionInfo);
runspace.Open();//Here Exception raised
```

Error Details:

> The WinRM client sent a request to an HTTP server and got a response
>   saying the requested HTTP URL was not available. This is usually
>   returned by a HTTP server that does not support the WS-Management
>   protocol

Comment: The uri.. If I am not mistaken, it should something be like `http://machineName:5985/wsman`. It does depend on how WSMan service is hosted on remote machine.. Unless you know it has to be accessed with uri you are already using, I'd suggest you try uri in this comment.

Comment: I recently happened to configure Exchange server 2013 on Windows Server 2012 R2 , all worked except “Exchange Management Shell”. This is what i followed ... http://www.windowstechinfo.com/2015/10/solved-the-winrm-client-sent-a-request-to-an-http-server-and-got-a-response-saying-the-requested-http-url-was-not-available.html

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, the uri that i used and worked is http://machinename/powershell**/** 
I had also similar error message with basic authentification, so using Kerberos is needed in some cases.